# Trouble tracking Facebook Like button with Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-analytics, facebook-like

I'm trying to track my Facebook likes with Google Analytics.

What I planned on doing was adding a jQuery event listener on the like button.

The like button is contained within a form with the id of "u_0_4", so I added this to header.php of my wordpress site (hearingcareblog.com):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#u_0_4").submit(function(){
        alert('test');
        //this is where I would have my tracking code
    });
});
</script>
```

but the alert doesn't come up when I click the like button.

Has anyone else tried this?

Any ideas as to why my jQuery wont listen to the form?

Comment: Why not just track your likes with the dashboard facebook provides?

Comment: my client would like all social interactions to be tracked with GA

Answer (score 2):

check out this blog post directly from google, which shows you how you can track the clicks: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial

the important part of the blog post is this piece of code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', targetUrl]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the form being added to the page dynamically? If so, and and if your `$(document).ready(...` runs before the form is in the dom, then the submit code won't fire.

Try executing `$("#u_0_4")` in either a FireBug or Chrome Developers Tools console window to double check that the form is being found.